# Check first character of a word in a string begins with @

Tags: javascript, regex

A few days ago I posted a similar question, but I do not quite understand the principle. Are there good resources where the replace function combined with regular expressions is explained?

Anyways, right now I have the following problem: A string which starts with `@` should be placed in an link. So `@test` should be replaced to `<a href="/test"> @test </a>`.

Also, these rules should apply:

1. The string can only contain one @, which is at the beginning.
2. If there are more strings, also replace them. I thought you can do this by putting `/g` behind the regex?

This is what I have so far:

```
value = "is @test";
var text = value.replace(/^.*(@)(\w+).*$/, "<a href='$2'>$1$2</a>");
```

My output

```
<a href="test">@test</a>
```

**EDIT:**
The link is now working. However, the word "is" is missing.

Comment: I made the title a bit clearer.  What is the expected output?  Is it `"is <a href="test">@test</a>`?  What if there are multiple @ characters?

Comment: I think you might need to replace ` value.replace(/([@])\w+/g, '<a href="$1">$1$2</a>');` to `value.replace(/^([@])\w+/g, '<a href="$1">$1$2</a>');

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Comment: Look at my updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the ambient text:

```
value = "is @test or what";
var text = value.replace(/^(.*)@(\w+)(.*)$/, "$1<a href='$2'>@$2</a>$3");
```

Or just capture less:

```
var text = value.replace(/@(\w+)/, "<a href='$1'>@$1</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

When performing a `.replace()`, you need to include all the characters in the RegExp that you wish to replace, preserving the ones you want to keep with parentheses.

```js
var test = 'is @test';
function makeAt(string){
  return string.replace(/^.*(@)(\w+).*$/, "<a href='$2'>$1$2</a>");
}
console.log(makeAt(test));
```

Comment: The link now works! However, the world "is" is now missing. I would like to have all the other words not changed. See my update.

Comment: Also, if I put an extra '@test' in the string, the last one disappears.